# How to signal to a process that spawns a subprocess that a message has been sent?

Tags: python, node.js, ipc, child-process, spawn

index.js spawns the subprocess.py.  I have two questions about this:

1. How should I signal to `subprocess.stdout` (index.js), *without closing* `sys.stdout` or `sys.stdin`, that the message has been sent?  Or, should I send an EOT from subprocess.py and interpret that as a message sent?
2. Why does the message get sent in multiple chunks (more than 1 byte) if `sys.stdout.flush` is called after reading each byte?

### index.js

```
let subprocess = spawn('python3', ['subprocess.py'], {
    'env': this.env,
    'cwd': __dirname,
});

let readable = Readable.from('message');

readable.on('error', () => { }).pipe(subprocess.stdin, { 'end': false });

subprocess.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log(data.toString('utf8'));
    //  message - in multiple chunks.
});
```

### subprocess.py

```
while True:

    data = sys.stdin.read(1)
    sys.stdout.write(data)
    sys.stdout.flush()
```